# Consecutive Days badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

A while ago I got the `Enthusiast` badge for being on Stack Overflow for a total of 30 consecutive days. `Enthusiast` is a silver badge: https://stackoverflow.com/badges/71/enthusiast

For 100 days on SO, you get a gold badge called `Fanatic` for being on the site for a total of 100 consecutive days.

I believe that these are way too spread out, and that the `Enthusiast` badge is too easy to obtain.

Why is it we have no bronze badge for consecutive days?

Surely it should be built up from bronze to gold, because silver was easy to get. Why not create a new bronze badge which you get for a total of 30 days, a silver badge for a total of 50 days, and a gold badge for 100 days?

Feature request:

- Bronze badge for 30 consecutive days
- Silver badge for 50 consecutive days
- Gold badge for 100 consecutive days

Comment: Personally, I want something for being on every day for a year. These piddly amounts of days mean nothing to me.

Comment: @DaveNewton, agree with you, but for that there should be a **Diamond badge** because consecutive for a year is very hard job.

Comment: @Lucifer It was depressingly easy :( That speaks more about the rest of my life than my dedication to SO, though ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton, 2 years on SO, and almost 3K answers, really nice dedication, i am impressed :)

Comment: @DaveNewton, you sound so defeated for someone with such an awesome track record. ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton: Meh. Hitting the rep cap every consecutive day for a year, or it's too easy ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet Hum... some people, not thinking of anybody especially, could get this without even having to log in in the year... Too easy. Let's make it 300 rep a day during a year.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's really no need to add such a badge. Every badge exists for a reason. These weren't just dreamed up based on someone's whim or because someone felt there needed to be some sort of dress-right-dress symmetry or rule where there must be 3 of something per category just because there are 3 classes of badges.

In this case, a bronze badge would accomplish nothing except waste some developer's time, who should instead be focusing on fixing bugs or tweaking the review system. However, 30 days says a lot about the health of the community and the dedication of the user. 30 days *is* easy to get, you are right about that, but it also means users with that badge have more than likely participated on the site in some manner.

Even if you're just refreshing the page and clicking on a question once per day, chances are you'll see something that interests you, and you'll post an answer, write a question, upvote a post, or leave a helpful comment. In short, most people with the silver Enthusiast badge have also done other things on the site. You may not be married to the site, but at one point in time, you were dedicated enough to visit for an entire month.

On the other hand, the gold Fanatic badge takes a *tremendous* amount of effort to achieve. Sure, the same techniques one might use to get the Enthusiast badge apply, but because we're now measuring 3 months and give or take a week, there are just so many more opportunities for someone to make a mistake, such as forgetting about UTC, or taking a day off. In fact, many people don't get this badge on their first run. On day 73 on Stack Overflow, the clock reset, and I had to start over. Still, while I was visiting everyday, I wrote lots of answers, upvoted plenty of content, and learned quite a bit just from reading other Q&As.

The point is, people who go on badge runs for these two badges are more likely to make positive contributions. A bronze badge won't even make a dent in the site in terms of helping it out.  Badges are designed to encourage users to do things that are beneficial to the site in some manner. Hope this makes sense!  Good luck! :)

**NOTE:** I see you're an Unsung Hero holder! Congrats on earning that one. For that badge, you likely answered a lot of questions that weren't getting a lot of views, so your contributions likely *really* helped out! Same rules apply. That badge was created for a very specific reason. :)

Comment: Really nice answer. I agree with you completely. Right now I have 53 days consecutive.. I got up to something like 40 previously, I usually browse so on my phone, but for one night I ran out of data, so it reset, I would have been closer to 100 by now, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we need bronze for consecutive days.

**Bronze Badge** : Bronze badges are awarded for basic use of Meta Stack Overflow. They are easy to earn.

```
Bronze badge for 30 consecutive days
```

30 consecutive day sounds bit harder. It is better for Silver badge. Actually silver badge suits it better as per **Silver badge**'s definition : Silver badges are awarded for longer term goals. Silver badges are uncommon, but definitely attainable if you’re interested.

The user who is interested in sharing knowledge and participating on site, should get this badge.

However a **Bronze Regular** for **7 Consecutive days** sounds nice. Award once on completing 7 Consecutive days.

Comment: So why not a shorter term then? Like 10 days, something easy to obtain for newer users.

Comment: @SmartLemon, yes agree with you on this, it should be for 7 Consecutive days(Week), like we have Silver badge for 30 Consecutive days(Month) and Gold badge for 100 Consecutive days(3 months ).

Comment: How about a Fresh-Air badge for *not* visiting 7 consecutive days ever during a month? Being here all day, every day, is not that good!

Comment: I don't get this. You open by saying that we don't need a consecutive day bronze badge, but then you close by proposing a consecutive day bronze badge.

Comment: @PopularDemand, as per Bronze's defination, they are easy to earn, so my point was, one should not wait for 30(4 week) consecutive days, simple 7(one week) days might be fair enough.